# Windows Workflow Foundation Tracking ActivityId - What Encoding is this?

Tags: c#, serialization, encoding, character-encoding, workflow-foundation-4

I am using Windows Workflow Foundation on a project, specifically the StateTracker, Instance Store and tracking components. The tracking for each instanciated workflow gets serialized to the database, and additionally I am able to deserialize this data using the following technique:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee960223(v=vs.100).aspx

The tracking deserializes into a large XML tree, representing the current state of the long running workflow, ie:

```
//...brevity
<activities z:Id="5" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2010/02/System.Activities">
      <SerializedInstanceLists z:Id="6" z:Size="4" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Activities.Runtime">
        <a:ActivityInstanceMap.InstanceList z:Id="7">
          <singleItem z:Id="8" z:Type="System.Activities.ActivityInstance" z:Assembly="System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Activities">
//...brevity
```

However, I have come across an issue where occasionally when our system code changes, the system-assigned ActivityIds of a particular Workflow design change as well. Since these IDs are referenced in the tracking, the workflows then refuse to load.

For example, before the code update:

```
Activity 1 ID: 1.2170
Activity 2 ID: 1.2337
Activity 3 ID: 1.2215
```

After the code update:

```
Activity 1 ID: 1.2170
Activity 2 ID: **1.2338**
Activity 3 ID: **1.2216**
```

A workflow that is currently at **Activity 3** will have tracking that deserializes as:

```
            <a:ActivityInstanceMap.InstanceList z:Id="129">
          <singleItem z:Ref="11" i:nil="true" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Activities"></singleItem>
          <a:ActivityId z:Id="130">AQE=</a:ActivityId>
        </a:ActivityInstanceMap.InstanceList>
        <a:ActivityInstanceMap.InstanceList z:Id="131">
          <singleItem z:Ref="109" i:nil="true" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Activities"></singleItem>
          <a:ActivityId z:Id="132">AacR</a:ActivityId>
        </a:ActivityInstanceMap.InstanceList>
        <a:ActivityInstanceMap.InstanceList z:Id="133">
          <singleItem z:Ref="95" i:nil="true" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Activities"></singleItem>
          <a:ActivityId z:Id="134">AaMR</a:ActivityId>
        </a:ActivityInstanceMap.InstanceList>
```

I have found that by comparing to a workflow whose tracking was instantiated with the new code, the difference is in the *AacR* and *AaMR* ActivityIds. Updating these to the correct values successfully repair the workflow.

**My question is this:**

Does anyone recognise the encoding used for these *AacR* and *AaMR* ActivityIds? If I can work out how to convert the 1.2216 ActivityId into this serialized tracking value, I will be able to programmatically repair workflows on the fly when this occurs.

I have found that the Ids are initially serialized into byte arrays via the following reference source, however I can't work out how they go from this into the above 4 character strings.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Activities/System/Activities/Runtime/ActivityInstanceMap.cs

The following article explains how ActivityIds are generated:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2011/06/08/wf4-visual-workflow-tracking-and-workflowinspectionservices.aspx

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
Convert.ToBase64String(activity.QualifiedId.AsByteArray())
```

:-)